# How to display SendOn / ReceivedOn fields on CRM email activity

Tags: forms, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Using Dynamics CRM I would like to add SendOn and ReceivedOn fields to the Email Activity form.

I understand that Actual Start and Actual End display these values but I can't seem to find any MSDN or authoritative source for confirmation.

Also - I cannot rename the existing fields to SendOn/ReceivedOn because the meaning would be different depending on whether the email direction is Outgoing or Incoming.

Is there somewhere to handle this requirement OOB?

Comment: Did you mean to say "Send"On, like "Send this in the future", or "SentOn"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is OOB solution for this situation. You can try with JScript or plugin.

If you prefer JavaScript, you can add JS webresource with method where you will check is mail outgoing or incoming. Based on that set display names for ActualStart and ActualEnd fields (sendOn, receivedOn). Ofcourse, if you find authoritative source for this (I didn't :) ) This method will be called on email form load.

I would try with adding two DateTime fields (sendOn, receivedOn), and one plugin for email entity who will be executed on email status change. Depends on new status, appropriate DateTime field is updated

Hope it helps